# c++ converting a binary string from little to big endian (reverse the bits)

Tags: c++, bitset, endianness

I'm searching for a simple way to convert a binary string from little to big endian representation. 
I'm working with bitset and found methods that flip\reset\set the bits, but I'm seeking for a method to simply reverse their order.
I've tried few posts and no success.
Could anyone be helpful, please?

```
for (unsigned long i = 0; i < match.size(); ++i) {
            std::bitset<16> b(i);
            std::bitset<16> b_reversed = ~b;
            std::cout << i << '\t';
            std::cout << b << '\t';
            std::cout << b_reversed << '\t';
            std::cout << b_reversed.to_ulong() << '\n'; 
        }
```

Comment: Big endian vs. little endian is about the order of the **bytes**, not the bits. `0x01 0x02` and `0x02 0x01` have opposite endianness.

Comment: What is _your_ criterion for little endian? The usual is that the the bytes get reversed in order but the bits within a byte stay the same [and are big endian].

Answer (score 0):

```
template<size_t n>
std::bitset<n> reverse(std::bitset<n> &set)
{
    std::bitset<n> result;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++)
        result[i] = set[n - i - 1];

    return result;
}

std::bitset<16> reverse16(std::bitset<16> &set)
{
    unsigned short n = static_cast<unsigned short>(set.to_ulong());
    return std::bitset<16>((n >> 8) | (n << 8));
}

for (unsigned long i = 5234; i < 5238; ++i) 
{
    std::bitset<16> a(i);
    std::bitset<16> b = reverse16(a);   
    std::bitset<16> c = reverse(a);
    std::cout << a << '\t';
    std::cout << b << '\t';
    std::cout << c << '\n';
    std::cout << std::hex << a.to_ulong() << '\t';
    std::cout << std::hex << b.to_ulong() << '\t';
    std::cout << std::hex << c.to_ulong() << '\n';
}
```

You can either reverse the bitset order exactly as reverse does, or you can reverse the bytes it's based on which the reverse16 does.

Copy paste, watch their output and let me know which one you want..